# Showing Number instead of date

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

This is very strange for me because in Libreoffice Calc, few dates are showing number for example 25 Aug 2022 is showing 44798 while 25 Sep 2022 is showing correct format on same cell ex. E22.

Local Setting : English (India)

Please help with the solution.

Comment: Did you try to set the cell's format to "date"? -- Anyway, this is not about programming.

Comment: Yes, It is set to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue arising from **conditional formatting**.

First, remove all formatting: right click into cell and **remove direct formatting**.
Next, make sure that the cell format is set to a date format.
The date should now be shown in the date format defined.

If you still want to have conditional formatting with a cell formatted as date, make sure to use a template that defines the cell format as date. Best option for me was to create a new template.